# SQL retrieve data from column with the most rows in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `movies` and a column named `movie_id`. And I want to get the most commonly occuring `movie_id` in the table.

Example data in column:

```
movie_id  
234  
343  
2928  
956  
73  
234  
234
```

So the outcome should be 234, because it has the most rows. I have never tried this so I really don't know how this can be achieved.

Comment: For which SQL-product? MySQL, SQL-Server, Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: @EugenRieck, it's not bigger, there are more 234's than other numbers.

Comment: Not bigger, i think it is count of values, i see 234 for 3 times

Comment: Well most records. In this strange exaple i made its 234

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider upvoting and/or accepting answers that were helpful/useful. That is the way this site works and also that would be a nice way of expressing your appreciation of time and effort people took to answer your question. (You can only accept one answer per question, but you can upvote more than one, [please see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") for more information.)

Answer (score 4):

depending on the sql might be something like

```
SELECT * FROM movies
WHERE
 movie_id=(SELECT movie_id FROM movies GROUP BY movie_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

that is, if I understand correctly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM movies
GROUP BY movie_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

For SQL-Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    movie_id
FROM movies
GROUP BY movie_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you want all tied (at the top) movies to be returned:

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM movies
GROUP BY movie_id
HAVING COUNT(*) =
    ( SELECT TOP 1  COUNT(*)
      FROM movies
      GROUP BY movie_id
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    )
```

Comment: +1, but if they want all the tied movies, it might be enough to just add `WITH TIES` after `TOP 1` to your second query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT movie_id FROM (
  SELECT
    movie_id,
    count(*) AS num
  FROM <tablename>
  GROUP BY movie_id
) AS baseview
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For **SQL-Server** use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM movies
GROUP BY(movie_id)
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```